# Dynamodb GSI for boolean value

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index, dynamodb-gsi

So I have this `notifications` table with the following columns:

- PK: (which stores the userId)
- sentAt: (which stores the date the notifications was sent)
- data: (which stores the data of the notification)
- Read: (a boolean value which tells if the user has read the specific notification)

I wanted to create a GSI to get all the notification from a specific user that are `not read` (Read: False)
So the partition key would be `userId` and the sort key would be `Read` but the issue here is that I cannot give a boolean value to the sort key to be able to query the users that have not read the notifications.
This works with scan but that is not the result I am trying to achieve. Can anyone help me on this? Thanks

```
const params ={
      TableName: await this.configService.get('NOTIFICATION_TABLE'),
      FilterExpression: '#PK = :PK AND #Read = :Read',
      ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        '#PK': 'PK',
        '#Read': 'Read',
      },
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':PK': 'NOTIFICATION#a8a8e4c7-cab0-431e-8e08-1bcf962358b8',
        ':Read': true, *//this is causing the error*
      },
    };
    const response = await this.dynamoDB.scan(params).promise();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we cannot have `bool` type value to be used as DynamoDB Partition Key or Sort Key.

Some alternatives you could actually consider:

1. Create a GSI with only Partition Key, `gsi-userId`. When you do the query, you can query with `userId` and filter by `Read`. This will at least help you in saving some costs as you do not need to scan the whole table. However, be aware of Hot Partitions. [Link](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/dynamodb-table-throttled/)
2. Consider changing the `Read` data type to `string` instead. E.g. It could be values such as `Y` or `N` only. As such, you will be able to create a GSI with `gsi-userId-Read` and this would fulfill what you need.